# How can I show a custom message instead "No Results Found" for empty categories in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I've searched lots of time and tried to find out the solution but I couldn't. I have some blank categories on my website. I want to show a custom message for all those categories. How can I do this?

Comment: Check out my answer please

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify or create category.php file if not exist and put this code there:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

<div class="entry">
<?php the_content(); ?>

 <p class="postmetadata"><?php
  comments_popup_link( 'No comments yet', '1 comment', '% comments', 'comments-link', 'Comments closed');
?></p>
</div>

<?php endwhile; 

else: ?>
<p>**YOU CUSTOM MESSAGE TO SHOW "NO POSTS" MESSAGE**</p>


<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This works and showing custom message for all the categories even the categories have some posts.